# netfilter event on packet locally processed ( netfilter C kernel module code)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, netfilter

If an incoming packet comes in AND is locally processed, is there a way to get 
notified of that event?

I'm currently using the NF_IP_LOCAL_IN hook. But it looks like this gives all packets destined for the interface. For example suppose tcp packet X comes to port 5000, and there is a socket listening on port 5000. I would like to receive that event.

To clarify, I mean I only want to receive packet X events. All other packets that are not processed locally, (i.e. those that generate ICMP destination unreachable I don't want to be notified about)

Comment: So you would like to be notified if there's a process listening on port 5000, and not be notified if there's no process listening? That's outside the knowledge of netfilter.

Comment: @ninjalj How about with connection tracking though. Doesn't that keep track of what listening sockets are currently in play?

Comment: @ajpyles: no, that keeps track of inferred TCP states according to TCP segments seen.

Comment: @ninjalj OK thanks. I'll need to come up with my own checking mechanism then Which may prove expensive. Is it possible to make a copy of the incoming packet for post processing? I.e. send NF_accept but continue processing the packet asynchronously.

Comment: @ajpyles: a copy (actually, a COW clone) of the packet is what AF_PACKET (i.e: tcpdump et al.) does.

Comment: @ninjalj, you mean struct nf_hook_ops nf; ... nf.pf=AF_PACKET would work ? In that case do I need to actually return anything from my hook function?

Comment: @ajpyles: no, I meant, depending on what exactly do you need to do, maybe an AF_PACKET socket on userspace would be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netfilter lives at L3/L4, so it only has access to information up to L4. OTOH, LSMs (Linux Security Modules) have hooks almost everywhere, including `socket_recvmsg`, which I think should be called only for the packets that you are interested in.

Now, whether you can use this depends on your situation. Is there a LSM already running on your environment? If the answer is yes, can you make and insert a policy for your LSM that would be enough for your purposes?

Comment: This looks interesting Can you clarify what LSM means?

Comment: @ajpyles: expanded abbrev. An example of a LSM is Selinux.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the interface must be lo.

Or I don't understand why LOCAL_IN hook doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: For example, suppose I have ONLY a listening socket on port 5000. packet X comes in port 5000 and packet Y comes in on 5001. Both events will be displayed in the LOCAL_IN hook. But  I would just like to get the event that packet X comes in ( because it is processed locally).

Comment: There is "socket" match module (xt_socket.c). Maybe it will help.